# Framework for Scalable Multithreaded Client/Server Network Application

Tags: java, networking, frameworks, scalable

Although the java.net.Socket and java.net.ServetSocket give me powerful networking capabilities I wouldn't want to go through the nitty gritties of creating and managing my own sockets and threads.

What open source Java Frameworks are available to create/deploy a Highly Scalable Multithreaded Client/Server Network Application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had success with Apache MINA (http://mina.apache.org/) in the past. It's been pretty easy to get started with and performance is fairly decent.

Comment: What exactly is MINA? Is it a Java library to be used in Java programs or do I need to build in C++?

Comment: It's a java framework that hides some of the threading and async I/O patterns and allows you to just build the logic for a server component. The quick start guide (http://mina.apache.org/mina-v20-quick-start-guide.html) has a good example about writing a time server component. From there, you can add filters and such as you need.

Comment: You say performance is fairly decent?... any reason why its not Good?

Comment: Does Apache MINA need to be present on my Hosting server or do I upload it there?

Comment: The company I work for build a core server component with it and it runs great for our needs. I just haven't profiled it myself. With MINA, you'd build a standalone program. If your hosting provider can run a Java program, then you should be able to deploy a MINA app.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out [Jboss Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty), which is built on the Java NIO. The performance is pretty decent.